# How can I round the elements of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, rounding

-replace each element with its integer 
for (2.72,4.34,9.82, 1.0,4.05,2.45)
cout 2 4 9 1 4 2.

i tried this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    double v[100],i;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>v[i];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        round(v[i]);
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cout<<v[i]<<" ";
}
```

but i get this error :

```
|10|error: invalid types 'double [100][double]' for array subscript|
|13|error: invalid types 'double [100][double]' for array subscript|
|16|error: invalid types 'double [100][double]' for array subscript|
```

Comment: Why are you using a double as an array subscript?

Comment: Also, arrays begin at **zero** in C++. So, instead of `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` use `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` (once you've made `i` an integral type).

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: thank you everyone. im pretty dumb. and tired. thanks. i fixed it, but now..is there a big difference between  for(i=1;i<=n;i++) and (i=0;i<n;i++)? i didnt have any issues with the first option.

Comment: *is there a big difference* -- There is a huge difference.  The first includes `n` in the loop, while the second doesn't.   If `n` is 100, that could mean the difference between a program working, or a program not working and you spending hours, possibly days, trying to debug what is wrong due to the off-by-one bug.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following questions and suggestions:

1. The iterator of an array should use an integer variable, not a double.
2. According to the example you gave, you should round down instead of rounding, so you should use floor instead of round. It should be `v[i] = floor(v [i]);`.
3. Generally speaking, if the array size is not fixed, dynamic allocation will be used. For example, use new function `double *v = new double[n];`, and remember to delete when using up.
4. Array v contains 100 elements. It starts from v[0], v[1]...to v[99], so variable I is better to start from 0 to prevent overstepping.

Answer (score 0):

(As this question was the top search on Google just now, here's an answer.) Use simply,

```
std::for_each(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](double& e){e = std::round(e);});
```

having

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iterator>
```

Needs thought if `v` decays to a pointer (which it might do if you refactor to using other functions with `v` as a parameter). Better really to use `std::vector<double> v(100)` from the get-go as the type and declaration for `v` with, remarkably, no further edits to your program necessary, beyond

```
#include <vector>
```

Comment: What if I want a new vector or the rounded vector? Not to change the original vector.

Comment: @JAgustinBarrachina: `std::transform` with a `std::back_inserter` would do that.